# Creating a container that doesn't need overflow:auto

Tags: html, css

Here is the link to the problem. http://garethjweaver.com/portfolio/gjw/index.php?page=gjw

Trying to create a container without having to use overflow. I have my main container for all of the content like so.

```
.container {
max-width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 10px;
}
```

So far so good, I test it by placing a border around it and it shows it covers all of the content.

Now when I try and do another container for another section it doesn't work. Like so.

http://jsfiddle.net/4wN8q/

This is the other container I'm trying to create..

```
.portfolio-container {    
width: 980px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;    
}
```

But when I add a border around it it doesn't cover all of the content, it just stays at the top covering nothing. overflow:auto can fix this although when I'm trying to make my images responsive the scroll bar shows up down the bottom and it doesn't scale and it will work if I take overflow out.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Updated to include the code for it

```
<div class="portfolio-container">

<div class="content-container">
<div class="content">
Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
     Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
     Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
     Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
     Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
     Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text


 </div>
<div class="arrows">
    <a class="portfolio-button" href="#">Visit Website</a>

    <a href="index.php?page=qwd"><i class="float-left fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a href="index.php?page=pf"><i class="float-right fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>

</div>


<div class="portfolio-images">

    <img class="image-padding"src="./images/cz1-chrome.png">
    <img src="./images/cz-chrome.png">

</div>
```

Comment: your fiddle doesn't show the exact issue. share us your full HTML. By the way in your fiddle, if you want to fix the issue, use word-break:break-all;

Comment: So for instance the portfolio-container contains text and pictures as shown in the edit. But when I add a border to see if it covers everything it just shows the border at the top which makes it look a like a thick line, if that makes sense.

Comment: I just add the code in jsfiddle and it is showing properly. check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4wN8q/3/. where is the pblm?

Comment: I've uploaded it to show you what I mean. http://garethjweaver.com/portfolio/gjw/index.php?page=gjw as you can see the border doesn't cover the whole section as it should

Comment: it looks like you missed clear:both property.

Comment: Fixed it, I can still use overflow, just had to change some image code

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the image stylings instead of removing overflow